# How to apply Leave one out cross validation with logistic regression and find the values of Coefficents?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, cross-validation

I have written a code that performs **logistic regression** with l**eave one out cross validation**. I need to know the value of coefficients for logistic regression. But the attribute model. Coefficients_ work only after the model have used fit function. But as I have performed Cross validation so I have not used fit function to train the model.

Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

reg=LogisticRegression()
loo=LeaveOneOut()
scores=cross_val_score(reg,train1,labels,cv=loo)
print(scores)
print(scores.mean())    

coef = classifier.coef_
```

I want to know coefficient values for my features in train1 but as I have not used fit method, How can I get the values of these coefficients?